# DataTable via correo

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, phpmailer

Quisiera saber si hay algún método de enviar una tabla formada con datatable a travez de correo, lo ideal es que al pulsar un boton se abra una ventana emergente en donde pueda ingresar la dirección de correo del destino y se deberia adjuntar la tabla por ejemplo en formato de pdf de forma automatica... la ventana emergente y el envio de correos ya lo he logrado usando phpmailer y el siguiente codigo

html

```
<button class="btn botonF5 mdl-button--primary mdl-button--raised dialog-button">
     <i class="material-icons">&#xE158;</i>                              
</button>
<dialog id="dialog" class="mdl-dialog" style="margin: auto; background: #3abac9;">
    <form id="formulario" method="post" action="php/enviar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" style="padding: 22px 0;">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" 
                   placeholder="Para" required
                   id="destino" name="destino" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,20}">
            <label style="visibility: visible "class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Usuario"><i class="material-icons">contact_mail</i></label>
            <label style="visibility: visible; text-align: right;" class="mdl-textfield__label"><div id="uinvalido"></div></label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield" style="padding: 22px 0;">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" 
                   placeholder="Asunto" required
                   id="asunto" name="asunto" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_-]{1,20}">
            <label style="visibility: visible "class="mdl-textfield__label" for="Usuario"><i class="material-icons">description
            </i></label>
            <label style="visibility: visible; text-align: right;" class="mdl-textfield__label"><div id="uinvalido"></div></label>
        </div> 
        <div class="campos">
            <label>Mensaje:</label>
            <textarea id="mensaje" class="cont_email" name="mensaje"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-dialog__actions" style="padding: 10px 0px 8px 0px;">
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button">CERRAR</button>
            <button type="button" class="mdl-button envia_email">ENVIAR</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</dialog>
```

este script es para enviar un correo

```
<script>
        $(".envia_email").on('click', function (v) {
            v.preventDefault();
            v.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var cod1 = document.getElementById("destino").value;
            destino = cod1;
            var cod2 = document.getElementById("asunto").value;
            asunto = cod2;
            var cod2 = document.getElementById("mensaje").value;
            mensaje = cod2;
            var denvio = {
                "v2": destino,
                "v3": asunto,
                "v4": mensaje
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "enviaemail.php",
                type: "post",
                data: "destino=" + destino + "asunto=" + asunto + "mensaje=" + mensaje,
                success: function (algo) {
                    if (algo === 'enviado') {
                        alert('exitoso');
                    } else if (algo === 'fallido') {
                        alert("fallido");
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("no enviado");
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

lo que aun no consigo es adjuntar la tabla en algún formato para ser enviada tambien en el correo, espero me puedan ayudar...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr una solución alternativa con algunas configuraciones en la propiedad `exportSettings` (cuando se establece `fileName: null` podría exportar a la variable) del DataTable .

Y quizas con un for o foreach recorrer los datos del campo para llenarlos.

Acá te dejo un enlace de la documentación para te empapes:

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html

Tienes el HTML, CSS, Javascript, el Ajax y varias cosas bien interesante.